# No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify Annotation Based Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I doing annotation based coding, I am trying to run the application with Spring, Hibernate configuration and it is failing with error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider 
specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen 
PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either
```

**Below is my code**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class CurrExDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CurrExDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.currencyExchange.currExDemo");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("showSql", true);
        props.put("databasePlatform", Database.MYSQL);
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        em.setJpaProperties(props);

        return em;
    }
}
```

What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are missing at least the JpaVendorAdapter

add it like this:

```
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(hibernateDialect);
emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
```

hibernateDialect is e.g. `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` but that depends on your database.